# How can I keep my API secret out of my next.js deploy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've built a small internal app using React and Next.js. I'm using an `.env` file [per their instructions](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) with my API key and secret.

My `api/hello.js` file does a simple

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const data = await fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/lists/abc123/cards?key=${process.env.KEY}&token=${process.env.TOKEN}`)
```

And yet when I build and deploy my app to production, inspect the JS files, and search "trello" in them, I'm able to see the key and secret right there.

Not quite sure what I'm doing incorrectly here. Would love some help. Thanks!

My `next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    KEY: process.env.KEY,
    TOKEN: process.env.TOKEN
  },
}
```

Comment: you are doing well, if you do not zqnt to expose your secret to browser you should have backend which proxy request from browser to trello and vice versa. Is the only way to reduce exposition to only one source of trust, your server

Comment: Show your `next.config.js` and name of the variables in `.env`. If you run `next build` you should not see `.env` variables in the your output JS files.

Answer (score 1):

Since Next.js 9.4 you can add `.env` file and add secrets there without third-party packages like `dotenv`.

***next.config.js***

```
require('dotenv').config();

// this code exposes your environment variables to the client-side. 
module.exports = {
  env: {
    KEY: process.env.KEY,
    TOKEN: process.env.TOKEN
  },
}
```

You're using the secret in API routes, so you don't need to expose them to client side. You can remove it:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    KEY: process.env.KEY,
    TOKEN: process.env.TOKEN
  },
}
```

To avoid exposing secrets, do not use the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix for them.

If you run `next build` you should not see `.env` variables in the output JS files.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. I don't use the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix for anything at the moment, just process.env.key or process.env.token. And when I run a build and prod deploy then inspect my the JS files on my page, I see the key and token (the secret) in there

Comment: @ZackShapiro, alright. If you have `next.config.js` please add it to the question. Try to just run build without deploy and see whether you have environment variables in the output files. We don't know what is your deployment process and it could be what causes it.

Comment: I just added it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. Let me ask a simple question here: my code to get data from trello is in `./api/hello.js`. I don't want my users who are on index.js to be be able to inspect the code and derive my key and token from those files. At the same time, I can still make my request to the Trello API to get the data I need. This *should* do that, correct?

Comment: Because I've just built and deployed and when I inspect the linked javascript files on my index page, I see: `fetch("https://api.trello.com/1/lists/abc123/cards?key=".concat("MY ACTUAL KEY HERE","&token=").concat("MY ACTUAL TOKEN"))` which obviously I don't want.

Comment: @ZackShapiro, you have wrong deployment. Generally, API routes in Next.js can be executed but server code is not exposed. So, when you see inspect `/api/hello` file in browser you should see the result of the execution (like trello data or whatever is returned in response) and not the source code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214476/discussion-between-zack-shapiro-and-nikolai-kiselev).